# which of these compilers has a bug, according to the standard?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

Given the following source code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct concept
{
    virtual void perform() = 0;
};


struct model : concept, enable_shared_from_this<model>
{
    void perform() override {
        cout << "my pointer is " << shared_from_this().get() << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // shared_ptr<concept> concept_ptr = make_shared<model>();
    shared_ptr<concept> concept_ptr { new model };
    concept_ptr->perform();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling under `gcc`, this code compiles and associates the internal `weak_ptr` with the address of `model`.

Under `clang` the code will not compile (error message included at the end)

If you replace the initialisation of `concept_ptr` with `shared_ptr<concept> concept_ptr = make_shared<model>();` it will compile on both.

Which is correct?

edit:

My version of clang is the one that ships with `Xcode`:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

edit2:

Just wanted to say thanks to everyone for contributing. 
If you're interested, the reason I want to do this is that I want an opaque interface to an implementation with shared-handle semantics. Some implementations (async ones) require that callback objects ensure that the implementation object still exists (argues for `shared_from_this` and `weak_ptr::lock`). Other implementations do not require this. I wanted to avoid encumbering the concept (public interface) with the `enable_shared_from_this<>` base class, since that couples implementation with interface - a known evil.

In most cases, it's reasonable to use make_shared to create the implementation object. In rarer cases that require a custom destructor, the following seems portable:

```
    auto concept_ptr = static_pointer_cast<concept>(shared_ptr<model> {
                                                        new model ,
                                                        [](model* self) {
                                                            // some_deletion_operation on self;
                                                        } });
```

appendix:
error message on clang:

```
In file included from /Users/richardh/Documents/dev/Scratchpad/tryit/tryit/try2.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:4013:35: error: no viable overloaded '='
            __e->__weak_this_ = *this;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
...etc...
```

Comment: Provide compilation commands and compiler versions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it turns out it's a difference in the implementation of libstdc++ and libc++.

Comment: @RichardHodges: You should still always provide compilation commands and compiler versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand that libstdc++ follows the standard more closely here.

Concerning the requirements for

```
shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this(); 
shared_ptr<const T> shared_from_this() const;
```

both N3337 §20.7.2.4 (7) and N3936 §20.8.2.5 (7) only require

> `enable_shared_from_this<T>` shall be an accessible base class
>   of `T`. `*this` shall be a subobject of an object `t` of type `T`. There shall
>   be at least one `shared_ptr` instance `p` that owns `&t`.

There is no requirement named that one `shared_ptr` owning `&t` actually has to be a `shared_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<A_to_T_Convertible>`.

And that very function is the core of that class' functionality.

Thus, given `Tp` as the actual param of the `enabled_shared_from_this` and `Tp1` as the actual parameter of that owning `shared_ptr`, `is_convertible<Tp1, Tp>::value == true`, let alone `is_same<Tp1, Tp>::value == true`, is not required by the standard, same for respective pointers.

---

And indeed, the full output of clang++ using libc++ has

```
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3997:35: error: no viable overloaded '='
                __e->__weak_this_ = *this;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4035:5: note: in instantiation of
      function template specialization
      'std::__1::shared_ptr<concept>::__enable_weak_this<model>' requested here
    __enable_weak_this(__p);
    ^
[...]enable_shared.cxx:34:25: note: in instantiation
      of function template specialization
      'std::__1::shared_ptr<concept>::shared_ptr<model>' requested here
    shared_ptr<concept> model_ptr1(new model);
                        ^
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4942:15: note: candidate function not
      viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::shared_ptr<concept>' to 'const
      std::__1::weak_ptr<model>' for 1st argument
    weak_ptr& operator=(weak_ptr const& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
              ^
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4953:15: note: candidate function not
      viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::shared_ptr<concept>' to
      'std::__1::weak_ptr<model>' for 1st argument
    weak_ptr& operator=(weak_ptr&& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
              ^
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4949:9: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
        operator=(weak_ptr<_Yp> const& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
        ^
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4960:9: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
        operator=(weak_ptr<_Yp>&& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
        ^
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4967:13: note: candidate template
      ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Yp = concept]
            is_convertible<_Yp*, element_type*>::value,
            ^
```

So libc++ here wants

```
is_convertible<Tp1* /*= Base* = concept**/, Tp* /*= Derived* = model* */>
```

which of course fails here, that the run-time `*this` of that very `shared_ptr<Tp1>` would be `dynamic_cast`-able to `Tp*` is out of ansatz here.

---

From this perspective, it's also clear why `shared_ptr<concept> concept_ptr = make_shared<model>();` doesn't suffer from that; on the `rhs` there is a `shared_ptr<Tp /* = derived = model */>` constructor and for that `ptr` `is_convertible` holds.

---

libstdc++ doesn't suffer from this, because it passes the **argument**, thus its type (= Derived = model), of the `shared_ptr<Tp1 /* = Base = concept*/>` constructor down to the internal `weak_ptr<T /*= Derived = model*/>` assignment, not the `shared_ptr` in construction.

https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L848

```
  template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
    class __shared_ptr
{
```

https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L858

```
template<typename _Tp1>
explicit __shared_ptr(_Tp1* __p)
    : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p)
{
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_ConvertibleConcept<_Tp1*, _Tp*>)
  static_assert( !is_void<_Tp1>::value, "incomplete type" );
  static_assert( sizeof(_Tp1) > 0, "incomplete type" );
  __enable_shared_from_this_helper(_M_refcount, __p, __p);
}
```

https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L1459

```
  template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
    class __enable_shared_from_this
    {
```

https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L1482

```
private:
  template<typename _Tp1>
void
_M_weak_assign(_Tp1* __p, const __shared_count<_Lp>& __n) const noexcept
{ _M_weak_this._M_assign(__p, __n); }


  template<typename _Tp1>
friend void
__enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<_Lp>& __pn,
                 const __enable_shared_from_this* __pe,
                 const _Tp1* __px) noexcept
{
  if (__pe != 0)
    __pe->_M_weak_assign(const_cast<_Tp1*>(__px), __pn);
}
```

My point of view only; comments welcome.

@Richard Hodges: +1, very interesting topic

Comment: This is a really thorough investigation, thank you. I think what you're saying is that my actual use case is not covered by the standard, and that it happens to work on libstdc++ through a fortunate choice of implementation detail.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this works for libstdc++ by fortunate implementation choice only; I'd say it has to work. The standard is not exactly famous for being orthogonal, but if it doesn't clip it to a certain set of valid type params for the "owning" shared_ptr involved, I'd postulate *a pointer is a pointer is a pointer* for which the analogon of Base* p = new Derived must be legal, regardless of any intrinsic voodoo.

Comment: @TC remarked on my answer than the libc++ issue was related to [bug 18843](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18843).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thx for the cleanup! *It seems I live on the edge when it comes to formatting inlined code*. Maybe we should drop the assignee of that bug report a short note; shouldn't we?

Comment: @Solkar: Howard Hinnant (the assignee of the bug and author of libc++) is a member of the Standard Library committee, it would be interesting to get his opinion on the matter indeed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. , Richard Hodges: dropped a comment pointing to this thread at aforementioned llvm bug #18843 http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18843#c4

Comment: If it helps the libc++ development effort, I'm very happy to have spent the time to ask this question.