# CLANG vs. GNU Compilers Collection - Compiles in GNU but fails in CLANG

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mavericks, clang++, ace

I am trying to compile my project with 3rd party lib "ACE 6.2.8" in MAC OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks with clang++.

I get the following error:

```
In file included from ../../../Client/Chromodoris/Agent/CacheGenerator.cpp:15:
In file included from ../../../Client/Chromodoris/Agent/ACEIncludes.h:22:
In file included from ../../../Client/Chromodoris/ExternalLibs/ACE_wrappers/ace/OS.h:53:
In file included from ../../../Client/Chromodoris/ExternalLibs/ACE_wrappers/ace/Cleanup.h:30:
In file included from ../../../Client/Chromodoris/ExternalLibs/ACE_wrappers/ace/Intrusive_List.h:128:
In file included from ../../../Client/Chromodoris/ExternalLibs/ACE_wrappers/ace/Intrusive_List.inl:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:627:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4013:35: error: no viable overloaded '='
            __e->__weak_this_ = *this;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
```

Is it possible that CLANG++ compiler have a problem? Is there any workaround?

Additional info:

```
Moamen-MacBook:ace Moamen$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Please notice my code is calling 3rd party lib (ACE) which calls the CLANG++ toolchain where the problem occurs.

Notice same code compiles under the GNU Compiler collection.
I believe this issue is relevant:
[which of these compilers has a bug, according to the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851110/which-of-these-compilers-has-a-bug-according-to-the-standard)

Comment: You need to provide a code sample otherwise we will just be guessing.

Comment: The upcoming ACE 6.3.0 will have a set of fixes for clang-600 but not sure if this specific error is triggered by ACE or some application code.

Comment: Can you please tell when 6.3.0 will be released?

Comment: Probably this Friday, latest next Monday as far as current testing shows

Comment: Release scripts are running, ACE 6.3.0 should be available today

Comment: ACE 6.3.0 is now available, see www.orbzone.org/node/368 for the release announcement

Comment: Thanks! I will check it hoping all will be OK

Comment: And, how are the results?

Comment: The same! Seems my problem above is not related to ACE version, it's more about the link in the original topic.
To avoid the problem, I used the derived class instead of base in all relevant places, which solved the issue.

Comment: But, I have another problem (which occurs in ACE6.2.8 and ACE6.3.0) where I fail at linking:


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ACE_MUTEX_LOCK_CLEANUP_ADAPTER_NAME", referenced from:
      ACE_OS::rw_wrlock(ACE_rwlock_t*) in BrowserIntegrationRequestHandler.o

Comment: I will post additional topic for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.

I got a note message, 2-3 lines after the error above (sorry, don't have the message!), telling me that can't cast from base to derived class.

Use the derived class object instead of the base class object, and issue should be solved.
Notice - you may use the base class instead of the derived, but depends on you implementations and needs.